# Is it possible to code a Custom Attribute that breaks a build (like System.ObsoleteAttribute)?

Tags: .net, build, custom-attributes

I'd like to create a custom attribute that is executed during the build process and can break the build according to some logic, pretty similar to `System.ObsoleteAttribute`.

For instance, consider the following C# code (note that this is a simplified example):

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Check]
    public int MyProp { get; private set; }
}
```

This `Check` attribute should check that the property it decorates has a public setter. Since `MyProp` property doesn't have a public setter (it has a private setter), the `Check` attribute should break the build.

Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only version of the C# spec that can be linked to is for the 2003 version (other versions of the spec are in word format). It defines a concept of ["Reserved Attributes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664620(v=vs.71).aspx). These attributes are specially dealt with be the compiler. `ObsoleteAttribute` is one of these.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the reference, nice to know! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - at least, not at the moment, with the standard build tools. It's entirely possible that when the "compiler as a service" project ships, that may expose this functionality. But the C# compiler only really changes its behaviour a few well-known attributes.

Two options you might want to consider:

- Post-processing with something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features)
- Unit test to find all the attributes and check them that way

Personally I'd probably go with the latter... although really, there's not much obvious benefit - if you remember to declaratively add the `[Check]` attribute, aren't you going to remember to add the public setter? Or to put it another way: if you *forget* to put on the public setter, aren't you just as likely to forget to include the attribute?

Comment: The `Check` attribute does more than just checking. It has some business logic, which fails (and causes invalid business state) if the property lacks a public setter. That's the motivation...

Comment: @Ron: Right, that makes more sense (and maybe worth mentioning in a question edit). I stand by my advice of writing a test to verify this - it's easy enough to loop through all types in an assembly and all properties in a type.